# Duplicate Product Code report

Tags: reporting, product

I am trying to create a scheduled report that will come out daily when a duplicate product code has been entered. What formula can I use for this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this with a formula.  Since the Salesforce duplicate management feature doesn't support Product object [Vote for this Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DuBuAAK), you will have to look for duplicate management apps on AppExchange like DupeCatcher, Cloudingo, Apsona etc to prevent dupe creation and/or to find existing dupes.

Comment: I downloaded DupeCatcher, but that didn't seem to work for Products either...any suggestions?

Comment: You'll have to research the other apps.  If none support Product, then probably the only solution is to write an Apex trigger that prevents duplicate product code creation.